# R Markup not Kniting - Error (Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'False' not found)

Tags: r

I am trying to create an R Markup document for a few analysis.

But a particular section of my code is giving me an error as below:

> "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'False' not found
>   Calls:  ... process_group.block -> call_block -> eval_lang -> eval -> eval
>   Execution halted"

The code actually works independently but not in the Markup and the code I am trying to run here is in the lines of the below:

```
suppressMessages(library(reshape2))
suppressMessages(library(ggplot2))
suppressMessages(library(gridExtra))

Customer.Code <- c("200091", "200092", "200093", "200094","200091", "200092", "200093", "200094")
variable <-c("Company.Customer.service","Company.Customer.service","Company.Customer.service","Company.Customer.service", "Competitor.Customer.service", "Competitor.Customer.service", "Competitor.Customer.service", "Competitor.Customer.service")
value <- c("5","4","5","5","3","4","4","4")

pmelt <- data.frame(Customer.Code, variable, value, stringsAsFactors=F)

pmelt$Status <- ifelse(pmelt$variable %in% c("A.E.Customer.service","A.E.Delivery","A.E.Product.Availability") , "ANE" , "Competitor")

p <- ggplot(pmelt, aes(x = variable, y=value)) + geom_boxplot(aes(colour = Status))  + geom_jitter(width = 0.2) + ggtitle("ANE Vs Competitor") + xlab("Aspects") + ylab("Ratings") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333", angle=45), axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333"), title = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333"))

grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p))
```

Can anyone help out on what I am doing wrong here

Comment: The error message suggests that you misspelled `FALSE` as `False` somewhere.

Comment: You don't show options for the chunk - I guess the mispelled `False` is there.

Comment: Also, please post the actual code you’re using — the code you posted would be good to reproduce the problem — except it’s not RMarkdown code.

Answer (score 4):

I have spent quite some time researching it and what I found that fixes it is to clean up knit's cache and let this parameter below set to false:

```
{r setup, include=TRUE, cache = FALSE}
```

Hope that helps, I saw other answers over here, but didn't get to the very core of the problem, at least to what I have see! Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I received the same error message in R today. Similar to what folks suggested above, checking through all code blocks and making sure that FALSE is all capitalized fixed my issue. I had some code blocks with parameter set to equal to "False" instead of "FALSE" and that was the culprit. It would not knit because of that.